# Regex to find and replace a status sentence

Tags: php, regex

A system message may include the following status sentence:

> This function was executed **312** times, most often used by process **Urbanus**: **16.06.2012 14:10**.

The sentence always is in one line.

I need to:

1. Retrieve the three bold parts:

   - An integer between 1 and n (here: 312)
   - A string consisting of characters, symbols (incl. whitespaces but excl. newline) and numbers (here: Urbanus)
   - A date which is either "Today" or "Yesterday" or a date in DD.MM.YYYY (here: 16.06.2012)
   - A time in 24hrs hh:mm format (here: 14:10)
2. Remove the whole sentence from the system message.

I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
$matches = preg_replace(
"/This function was executed ([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]) times, most often used by process (.+?): ((Today|Yesterday|[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}))./iU", 
"", 
$message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1part:

Try use `preg_match_all`. Also I improve your pattern

```
$message = 'This function was executed 312 times, most often used by process Urbanus: 16.06.2012 14:10.';

$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all("/This function was executed ([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]+) times, most often used by process (\w+?): ((Today|Yesterday|[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}))./i", $message, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Comment: \w does not match whitespaces, has to be [\w\ ]. Whatever is meant by 'Symbols' it might be necessary to go with something like [^:\n].

Comment: @Sergey Thanks, but it's not matching for me. Further, if I use preg_match(_all), it does not replace the matched sentence, does it?

Comment: @Lucas Hoepner By "Symbols" I mean colon, comma, semicolon, exclamation mark, etc.

Comment: @FletcherDuran I currently do not have enough time on my hands to figure it out for you, as much as I would like to, just try http://myregexp.com/ until it works ;)